# ISO-8859-1 not displaying correctly certain characters

Tags: html, utf-8, iso-8859-1

In the website I'm developing there are several european characters such as ã or ç. I was told to change from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1, but ISO doesn't seem to code these characters correctly, while UTF-8 marks several others as question marks. Right now, the tag on my header is this one:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Comment: Why use `ISO` anything over `UTF`? The whole point of `UTF` is that it supports everything.

Answer (score 0):

Use only UTF-8 if you want to avoid problems, the ISO encodings will bring you nothing good.

Comment: The problem is that UTF brings problems aswell. The € symbol shows up as a question mark for example...

Comment: No, you did not use the proper codes, thats why you see garbage. UTF allows you to write any Unicode code inside the page. Read this, even if is old you need to get the basics first http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @user3058888 There's no Euro character in ISO-8859-1. If the Euro character shows up as question mark, your content might be encoded as ISO-8859-15 which is not a subset of Unicode.